# iOS HLS (Http Live Streaming) start from lower bandwidth.

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming

How do you choose low/medium bandwidth to start HLS streaming (using AVFoundation) from variant playlist. I assume it'll automatically switch to higher resolution based on reachability/connection and client bandwidth dynamically. But how do you make sure that the steaming begins with a low/medium bitrate? BTW, I noticed that Coursera's (iOS app) video player does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always starts with the first entry in the variant playlist:

> The first entry in the variant playlist will be played at the initiation of a stream and is used as part of a test to determine which stream is most appropriate. The order of the other streams is irrelevant.
>
> *Therefore, the first bit rate in the playlist should be the one that most clients can sustain.*

Source: [Apple Technical Note TN2224](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745-CH1-BITRATERECOMMENDATIONS)

Comment: In my experience this is no longer guaranteed. I tested multiple HLS playlists and the first segment to play was always the one closest to the observed bitrate.

Comment: @Chris it might have changed recently but until they update the docs it's safer to follow the existing recommendations.

Comment: Fair enough...but I first saw this in iOS 7. It's possible Apple just aren't updating that doc like many others. I've sent Feedback on that TN so maybe they will clarify.

Comment: @ChrisH Great, keep me posted please!